# Cross Sub - Domain creation

Tags: web, web-development-server

I have parked my website domain with a provider (XYZ). I have hosted the site at a separate host provider (Friend of mine - server). I need to create a sub domain for my website now ? When I checked the domain providers site the option is not available. How do i create a sub domain now ? Should I check with the hosting provider of the site ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can anonymous downvoters please come forwards and tell the OP what you think is wrong with the question otherwise it is very hard for them to learn!

Comment: Thanks for the suppport @JulianKnight! Don't know why they downvote the questions ?

Comment: No problem. There seem to be a lot of downvoting lurkers on SO who don't have the courtesy or sense to say why they are downvoting so that people can improve. If I flag or downvote I make sure people understand why so they get the chance to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpark the domain first.

You can either point the domain at your friends server too or tell the system your provider uses to offload it's DNS responsibilities for your domain to your friends DNS provider (this is not a transfer, it simply says that any DNS queries for your domain are handled elsewhere).

You cannot do anything with a parked domain.